# Spliting a txt file in to words by strsplit in R, why are there still spaces left?

Tags: r

I am trying to split a txt file in to single words. 
suppose the dataset name is "x"
my code is:
    `k <- unlist(strsplit(sub_total, "[^A-Za-z]"))`

then I sort it and find the most frequent words.

```
tail(sort(k))
```

the result is

```
     you     a     I    to   the

    2770  3442  4104  4541  5572 44833
```

the last element has a frequency of 44833, does it represent space? The spaces should be deleted when spliting the txt, is that right? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have punctuation or double spaces?

```
> sub_total <- "A dog walks the beach"
> unlist(strsplit(sub_total, "[^A-Za-z]"))
[1] "A"     "dog"   "walks" "the"   "beach"
> 
> sub_total <- "A dog walks the  beach"
> unlist(strsplit(sub_total, "[^A-Za-z]"))
[1] "A"     "dog"   "walks" "the"   ""      "beach"
```

Comment: the txt is a dataset from blogs and twitter, I think there should be many double spaces and punctuation. I think that is the problem, Thanks a lot!